# ASP.NET MVC Javascript Inserting Indexed Fields Into a List

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a simple survey application and I am experiencing trouble accessing the survey's questions.

**Survey Model**

```
public class Survey
{
    public Survey()
    {
        Questions = new List<Question>();
        CompletedBy = new List<CompletedSurveys>();
    }

    public int SurveyID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

**Question Model**

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public int SurveyID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And I auto generate input fields for the questions using the code below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Questions['+ itemIndex +'].QuestionID"></input>
```

Which renders to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].QuestionID">
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems like I am inserting the questions into the list incorrectly. Since my model's questions are always null.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us the code where you render the `<input>`'s you mentioned

Comment: Where are you setting the value of the input?

Comment: You are not setting the `value` attribute. Always use the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods to generate you form controls correctly (and you will need a `for` loop of `EditorTemplate` as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943))

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to JavaScript for generating `hidden fields` in this case. You can do it with a loop and `@Html.Hidden` like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.Hidden(Model.Questions[i].QuestionID.ToString())   
}
```